# Binary algorithm for calculating greatest common divisor of big integers

Tags: c, biginteger, bigint

In order to calculate GCD of two Big Integers, I used binary algorithm and save big integers in arrays to calculate the GCD of two big integers efficiently.

**Input**

One line containing two integers, a and b, where 0 < a, b < 10^256

**Output**

Please output an integer representing gcd(a, b).

**Time limits**

1 s

**Sample Input 1**

20210208 80201202

**Sample Output 1**

6

**Sample Input 2**

987654321987654321987654321 123456789123456789123456789

**Sample Output 2**

9000000009000000009

I have tried worst case scenario like 10^256 - 1 and 1, which is can be calculated within 1 s. Also ,
I have passed sample test and some other test data. However, when I upload code down below to the judge system, most of the test data shows *TLE* and few even shows *WA*. What's the problem of my code？ Is there any other worse scenario cases that I missed ?

[pseudo code of Binary Algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmOk1.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 256

void rev(char *string, int len);
bool zero(int *to_array, int size);
void divided_by_2(int *ptr, int size);
bool comparison(int *m, int *n, int size);
void substraction(int *m, int *n, int size);
void twice(int array[], int k, int size);


int main(void){
    char string_1[SIZE], string_2[SIZE];
    scanf("%s%s", string_1, string_2);
    int len_a = strlen(string_1);
    int len_b = strlen(string_2);

    char string_a[len_a], string_b[len_b];
    strcpy(string_a, string_1);
    strcpy(string_b, string_2);
    /*reverse the string*/
    rev(string_a, len_a); 
    rev(string_b, len_b);

    int max_size = len_a;
    if (len_b > len_a)
        max_size = len_b;

    int a[max_size], b[max_size];
    for (int i = 0; i < max_size; i++){
        if (i >= len_a)
            a[i] = 0;
        else
            a[i] = string_a[i] - '0';
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < max_size; i++){
        if (i >= len_b)
            b[i] = 0;
        else
            b[i] = string_b[i] - '0';
    }
    int k = 0; /* k for power*/
    int *m = a, *n = b;
    /*binary algorithm for GCD */
    while(!zero(m, max_size) && !zero(n, max_size)){
        if (m[0] % 2 == 0 && n[0] % 2 == 0){
            k++;
            divided_by_2(m, max_size);
            divided_by_2(n, max_size);
        }else if (m[0] % 2 == 0)
            divided_by_2(m, max_size);
        else if (n[0] % 2 == 0)
            divided_by_2(n, max_size);
        
        if (comparison(n, m, max_size)){
            int *temp = n;
            n = m;
            m = temp;
        }
        
        substraction(m, n, max_size);
    }
    twice(n, k, max_size);

    bool zero = true;
    for (int i = (max_size - 1); i >= 0; i--){
        if (n[i] != 0 && zero)
            zero = false;
        if (!zero)
            printf("%d", n[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void rev(char string[], int len){
    char rev[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        rev[i] = string[len - i - 1];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        string[i] = rev[i];
    }
}

bool zero(int *to_array, int size){
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if (to_array[i] != 0)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

void twice(int *array, int k, int size){
    int carry = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        for (int index = 0; index < size; index++){
            int digit = array[index];
            if (digit == 0 && carry == 0)
                 continue;
        
            digit *= 2;
            digit += carry;
            if (digit >= 10){
                array[index] = digit % 10;
                carry = digit / 10;
            }else{
                array[index] = digit;
                carry = 0;
        } 
    }
}

void divided_by_2(int *ptr, int size){
    int digit = ptr[0];
    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++){
        if (index == size - 1){
            ptr[index] = digit / 2;
            break;
        }
        int prev = ptr[index + 1];
        if (prev % 2 == 0)
            ptr[index] = digit / 2;
        else{
            ptr[index] = (digit + 10) / 2;
            ptr[index + 1] -= 1;
        }
        digit = ptr[index + 1];
        }
}

bool comparison(int *m, int *n, int size){
    bool larger = false;
    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++){
        if (m[index] > n[index])
            larger = true;
        else if (n[index] > m[index]){
            larger = false;
        }
    }
    
    return larger;
}

void substraction(int *m, int *n, int size){
    int borrow = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        int digit = m[i] - n[i];
        digit -= borrow;
        if (digit >= 0){
            m[i] = digit;
            borrow = 0;
        }else{
            m[i] = digit + 10;
            borrow = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `system("pause")`?? Really!? Does your online judging system run Windows and press enter to continue?

Comment: Did you try posting to your online judging system after you removed the `system("pause");` line like you did here? How are we supposed to help when the code you post here does not match exactly with the problem you're describing?

Comment: When I upload the code to online judge system, I deleted the line of ```system("pause")```. Thanks for the reminds, anyway.

Comment: I doubt (10^256−1, 1) is the worst case. That does as many subtractions as there are 1 bits set in the binary of 10^256−1. (2^850−1, 1) would have more subtractions. And there may be worse cases. In the traditional Euclidian GCD algorithm, the worst case is consecutive Fibonacci numbers, if I recall correctly, and there might be something similar here.

Comment: Although this is a binary GCD, you are doing work in decimal, and with just one digit per word. The intent of the exercise might be to convert the inputs to true binary, with multiple bits per word, do all the work in binary, then convert the result to decimal.

Comment: It is wasteful to do all the work at `max_size` since the numbers get smaller as the algorithm progresses. The size should be reduced as the numbers get smaller. This also means the `zero` routine can remove its loop; a number will be zero if and only if its size has become zero.

Comment: The code reverse strings and copies them multiple times unnecessarily. The `rev` code is wasteful; it reverses into a temporary buffer in back, but a string reverse can be done in-place with swaps.

Comment: The output code inefficiently tests and maintains `zero` throughout. It is faster, and even easier, to first find the first non-zero digit, then print all digits from that point on.

Comment: In spite of the inefficiencies noted above, I am surprised the program would exceed a one second time limit. Perhaps there is some bug causing a loop?

Comment: In addition to @EricPostpischil's excellent comments, I notice your code does not handle negative numbers correctly. It also does not compute GCD(x, 0) correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for @EricPostpischil's incisive comments. I will try to convert the algorithm into true binary and improve the efficiency of the code.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Thanks for the reminds,  but a and b are integers which can never be 0.